# Exclude ps itself from ps output

Tags: bash, debian, ps

I want to get information about all processes in the system *except the `ps` process* itself.

That is, something like:

```
ps --no-headers --pid 1111 -N
```

where *`1111`* is the process id of the *currently* running `ps` command.

I tried something like

```
ps --no-headers --ppid $$ -N
```

However, this does ***not work*** when `ps` is running in a "subprocess" like:

```bash
IFS=' ' read pctd proc <<<$(/bin/ps --no-headers --ppid $$ -No pcpu,pid,comm --sort=+pcpu | tail -n 1)
```

This last command tries to get the CPU usage percentage and process id plus name of the process using the most CPU "recently".

```
IFS=' ' read pctd proc <<<$(/bin/ps --no-headers -eo pcpu,pid,comm --sort=+pcpu | tail -1)
```

was working OK until recently. However, [after update to Ubuntu 23.04 (or kernel 6.x) `ps` started *sometimes* listing itself as using 100% CPU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1464753).

---

For the time being, the following seems as a workaround (but it is not safe):

```
IFS=' ' read pctd proc <<<$(/bin/ps --no-headers -eo pcpu,pid,comm --sort=+pcpu | grep -v \ ps | tail -1)
```

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve in the last line?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To exclude `ps` itself:

```
sh -c 'exec ps --no-headers --pid "$$" -N'
```

`sh` substitutes its own PID for `$$`, but then it replaces itself with `ps`. PID does not change, this is how `exec` works. This way `ps` receives its own PID as the option argument to `--pid`.

Note this method excludes *the* `ps` itself but not other `ps` processes (if any).

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work also: `bash -c 'exec /bin/ps --no-headers --ppid "$$" -No pcpu,pid,comm --sort=+pcpu' | tail -1` produces (sometimes) `100    7321 ps` . :(

Comment: @FedKad `--pid` and `--ppid` are not equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. That is a very clever solution. In my case, the code is something like `IFS=' ' read pctd proc <<<$(sh -c 'exec /bin/ps --no-headers --pid "$$" -No pcpu,pid,comm --sort=+pcpu' | tail -n 1) ; echo $pctd $proc`. I will accept this answer, if there is no other shorter one.

Comment: In `bash` you can use `... $(exec ps --pid "$BASHPID" ... )` instead, no need of an additional sh/bash process

Comment: Sorry, but I tried the command `IFS=' ' read pctd proc <<<$(exec /bin/ps --no-headers --pid "$$" -No pcpu,pid,comm --sort=+pcpu | tail -n 1) ; echo $pctd $proc`, but it ***did*** report `ps`.

Comment: @FedKad `$BASHPID` not `$$`. It's _either_ `$(sh -c 'exec ps --pid "$$" ...' ...)` as indicated by Kamil, _or_ just `$(exec ps --pid "$BASHPID" ... )`

Comment: @LL3 I am terribly sorry for the confusion. You are right! And if it is OK for Kamil, you can extend his answer.

Comment: @LL3, `sh -c 'exec ps --no-headers --pid "$$" -N'` does add a process (it adds a `sh` execution though). See also `$sysparams[pid]` in zsh as an equivalent of bash's `$BASHPID`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, the `sh` execution is what I was referring to in my first comment with "additional sh process" :)

Answer (score 4):

As  a generalisation of *how to remove `ps` entry for itself*, especially for `ps` implementations that don't support the non-standard `-N`/`--deselect` option, a common approach is to do:

```
print_pid_and_run() {
  sh -c 'echo "$$" && exec "$@"' sh
}
print_pid_and_run ps ...ps-options... |
  awk 'NR == 1 {pid = $0; next}
       $1 != pid'
```

(change `$1` with the actual field that has the process pid in `ps`' output  depending on what option is passed to `ps`).

In zsh, running `sh` can be avoided by doing:

```
zmodload zsh/system
print_pid_and_run() (echo $sysparams[pid] && exec "$@")
```

In bash:

```
print_pid_and_run() (echo "$BASHPID" && exec "$@")
```

(bearing in mind that in `bash`, contrary to `zsh` above, that can't be used to run builtins or functions).

Answer (score 2):

Like this, using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) filter to discard `ps`:

```
$ read pctd pid proc < <(
    ps --no-headers -eo pcpu,pid,comm |
        awk '$1>=max && $3!="ps"{max=$1; val=$0}END{print val}'
)

$ echo $pctd 
11.1
$ echo $pid
1234
$ echo $proc 
process-name
```

[A more reliable way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/743755/12574), is to use `top`:

```
top -b -n1 | awk '/ PID /{p=1;next} p && !/top/{print $9, $12;exit}'
```

Comment: Unfortunately the `< <(...)` construct has the same problem. :(

Comment: The `awk` way works (because it does not run in a subprocess). However, I need to get the output into variables.

Comment: What is "not reproducible"? The `ps` command reporting itself using 100% CPU? You should try several times. It does not always act the same!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145519/discussion-between-fedkad-and-gilles-quenot).

Comment: See my edited post to discard `ps` itself

Comment: Thanks; that is an option to consider. Of course, there is no guarantee that the _only_ `ps` being ignored is the one we want!

Comment: Id I read title `Exclude ps itself from ps output`, this response is accurate

Comment: Check `top` added command

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer to your question, but a comment on your:

> ```
> IFS=' ' read pctd proc <<<$(/bin/ps --no-headers --ppid $$ -No pcpu,pid,comm --sort=+pcpu | tail -n 1)
> ```
>
> This last command tries to get the CPU usage percentage and process id plus name of the process using the most CPU "recently".

I doesn't and your approach is misguided there. `pcpu` returns the ratio of the time any CPU spent to run any thread of the process to the total time since the process came into existence.

So for instance, a process could start, spend a few ms initialising itself like when executing a command (during which it may use close to 100% of one CPU for 1ms), then sleep for 10 hours, then spawn 20  threads fully utilising 20 CPUs for 1 minute (during which `top` for instance would show 2000% CPU usage). If you run `ps -o pcpu` at that point, the process will have used 20 minutes of CPU over 601 minutes total, so you'll see something like 3%, not 2000%. If on the other hand, you happen to run that `ps` at the very moment a `sleep 1h` command is started, `ps` may find that that process has used 1 millisecond of CPU time over 1 millisecond, and report 100% CPU  utilisation.

If you want to get the process that is still running and has been using the most CPU time over the last say 3 seconds, you'd need to collect the CPU times of all processes at one point, then again 3 seconds later and  do the substractions, you can't use `ps -o pcpu` for that, or you could use some `top`-like application in batch mode which would do  the calculation for you.

Comment: Yes. You are right on this. And thank you for the clarification! However, my question should be considered only for what I ask in the title.